# Extract contents from given url

Tags: python

I am working with urls, I have a list of urls:

```
urls = ["https://www.linkedin.com/sales/lead/ACwAAAAuRQkBBY6nRLRXnmjHJfSztDdsJz4fOAw,NAME_SEARCH,j0rt?_ntb=lxOUzZ", "https://www.linkedin.com/sales/lead/ACwAAABS5-QBOBrFP_wlcbumeCdbNe0r9IY4dUg,NAME_SEARCH,mPxz?_ntb=lxOUzZHEQ%2Fy38"]
```

if you look at urls, I need to fecth whatever is there after /sales/lead/ and before first comma i.e., "ACwAAAAuRQkBBY6nRLRXnmjHJfSztDdsJz4fOAw" and "ACwAAABS5-QBOBrFP_wlcbumeCdbNe0r9IY4dUg" respectively.

desired output:

```
ACwAAAAuRQkBBY6nRLRXnmjHJfSztDdsJz4fOAw
ACwAAABS5-QBOBrFP_wlcbumeCdbNe0r9IY4dUg
```

Thanks

Comment: You show a list, how is this related to pandas?

Comment: The operation which is used here is pandas right

Comment: I need to fetch whatever is there after /sales/lead and before first comma

Comment: Can you use split? Is anything guaranteed about the URL - 
`[url.split("sales/lead/")[1].split(",")[0] for url in urls]`

Comment: pandas is not an operation, do you mean that you have your data in a pandas DataFrame? Please [edit] your question with the exact object, the logic will be different

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming a **list** as show in the question, use a regex with [`re.search`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search):

```
import re

out = [m.group(1) if (m:=re.search('/sales/lead/([^,]+)', url)) else ''
       for url in urls]
```

Output: `['ACwAAAAuRQkBBY6nRLRXnmjHJfSztDdsJz4fOAw', 'ACwAAABS5-QBOBrFP_wlcbumeCdbNe0r9IY4dUg']`

If you have a **DataFrame**, use [`str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'urls': urls})

df['out'] = df['urls'].str.extract('/sales/lead/([^,]+)')
```

Output:

```
                                                urls                                      out
0  https://www.linkedin.com/sales/lead/ACwAAAAuRQ...  ACwAAAAuRQkBBY6nRLRXnmjHJfSztDdsJz4fOAw
1  https://www.linkedin.com/sales/lead/ACwAAABS5-...  ACwAAABS5-QBOBrFP_wlcbumeCdbNe0r9IY4dUg
```

[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/oJKkbC/1)

Answer (score 2):

```py
import pandas as pd

urls = ["https://www.linkedin.com/sales/lead/ACwAAAAuRQkBBY6nRLRXnmjHJfSztDdsJz4fOAw,NAME_SEARCH,j0rt?_ntb=lxOUzZ",
        "https://www.linkedin.com/sales/lead/ACwAAABS5-QBOBrFP_wlcbumeCdbNe0r9IY4dUg,NAME_SEARCH,mPxz?_ntb=lxOUzZHEQ%2Fy38"]

output_url=[]
for url in urls:
  start_idx = url.find("/sales/lead/") + len("/sales/lead/")
  end_idx = url.find(",", start_idx)
  output_url.append(url[start_idx:end_idx])

print(output_url)
```

Output:

```
['ACwAAAAuRQkBBY6nRLRXnmjHJfSztDdsJz4fOAw', 'ACwAAABS5-QBOBrFP_wlcbumeCdbNe0r9IY4dUg']
```

Comment: What does `len()` do there? Can you please explain how your code works?

Comment: @Sotos here in the first element of list , url.find("/sales/lead/") gives you index at which 
 "/sales/lead/ " starts which is at index 24 and then length of "/sales/lead/" gives u 12 , so start_idx for first element is 36  , and then we try to find index of "," from the start index

Answer (score 0):

I like to use `urlparse` in such cases, i.e.

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

urls = ["https://www.linkedin.com/sales/lead/ACwAAAAuRQkBBY6nRLRXnmjHJfSztDdsJz4fOAw,NAME_SEARCH,j0rt?_ntb=lxOUzZ", 
        "https://www.linkedin.com/sales/lead/ACwAAABS5-QBOBrFP_wlcbumeCdbNe0r9IY4dUg,NAME_SEARCH,mPxz?_ntb=lxOUzZHEQ%2Fy38"]

for url in urls:
    path = urlparse(url).path
    lead_id = path.split('/')[3].split(',')[0]
    print(lead_id)
```

which gives,

```
ACwAAAAuRQkBBY6nRLRXnmjHJfSztDdsJz4fOAw
ACwAAABS5-QBOBrFP_wlcbumeCdbNe0r9IY4dUg
```